# Wrap text in table

Tags: tables, wrap, text-manipulation

I'm trying to convert my CV (originally assembled in word) into a Latex file, largely as a learning exercise. I just wondered if someone could help me wrap text as in my current version certain pieces of information seem to disappear off the edge of the page. Many thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling} 
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry} 


\usepackage{seqsplit}
%This package allows me to wrap text, or at least I thought it did!

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lp{.5cm}lp{1cm}|}
Research Interests \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, 
\\ \\
And also here and here and here.
    %This text hasn't been causing many any problem, its the material below that is difficult%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    \\\\

    \uppercase{\textbf{Education}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\
    2015-2019 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}University of Life\\ PhD in Life Skills\\ Thesis: ‘The Meaning of Life, without the number 7’\\ Supervised by Dr Smith\\ \end{tabular} \\
\\
2013 - 2014                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\University of Life\\ Masters in Life Skills\\ Thesis: ‘The Meaning of Life, without the number 6’\\ Supervised by Dr Smith\\ \end{tabular} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the desired ouput? From the code itself it is hard to see what you want to achieve. In your tables, you for example defined 4 columns but only seem to need 2.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me why you would need a table for the *research* interest bit anyway. Maybe you could just get away with using normal text? The problem here is that the research interest are in a `l` column of a table, where no automatic line breaks happen, so you would have to break lines yourself.

Comment: Is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/k345B.png (close to) what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @leandriis [I hope that makes sense], the example that you give it just what I was looking for! Ethan Duckworth's suggestion, while very helpful, isn't quite what I was looking for as I'd like to avoid using bullet points if possible

Comment: @JTLaTex, fair enough.  But you can get rid of the bullet points by changing ``{itemize}`` to ``{trivlist}``.  But it's true that you don't need lists at all, it's just that most of the CV packages seem to use lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}



\begin{document} 

\uppercase{\textbf{Research Interests}}

Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, 

And also here and here and here.


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\uppercase{\textbf{Education}} \\
2015-2019
& University of Life \newline PhD in Life Skills\newline Thesis: ‘The Meaning of Life, without the number 7’\newline Supervised by Dr Smith\\ 
\\ 
2013 - 2014                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
& University of Life\newline Masters in Life Skills\newline Thesis: ‘The Meaning of Life, without the number 6’\newline Supervised by Dr Smith \\

\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you really want tables at all?  Usually CVs are organized more with lists.  A table would have strictly defined rows and columns, but your line about "Write about research interests here, and here and here...." probably shouldn't be a row or a column.  And it's this line that goes off the edge of the page.

In any case, in LaTeX lines of text will wrap automatically in most contexts, the main exception is on columns that do not have a specified width.  Without a specified width, the column expands to fit the amount of material.  In order to make text wrap within a column, you need to define the width of the column.

Also you don't need the "table" environment, that's for when you want to create block of text (presumably containing a table) that can float to different parts of the document.

Here's how I would do what I think you're trying to do.  I've just re-implemented what you had, with minimal extra formatting.  There are packages on CTAN that format CVs, but just to understand the basics, I'd try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document} 

\begin{description}
\item[Research Interests]\ 
\begin{itemize}
\item Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, Write about research interests here, and here and here, 

\item 
And also here and here and here.
\end{itemize}

\item[Education]\ 
\begin{itemize}
\item 2015--2019 
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
University of Life\\ 
PhD in Life Skills\\ 
Thesis: `The Meaning of Life, without the number 7'\\ 
Supervised by Dr Smith
\end{tabular} 

\item 2013--2014
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
University of Life\\ 
Masters in Life Skills\\ 
Thesis: `The Meaning of Life, without the number 6'\\ 
Supervised by Dr Smith
\end{tabular}

\end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```